# Plot contour of vtk. file (from OpenFOAM) with Python-vtk module

Tags: python, vtk, openfoam

I have a vtk.file (pressure field) generated from cuttingPlane of OpenFOAM, in the format of Legacy, POLYGONS and Field Data:

```
    # vtk DataFile Version 2.0
        sampleSurface
        ASCII
        DATASET POLYDATA
        POINTS 55181 double
        0.312848 -0.389703 0
        -0.319252 -0.384475 0
        0.246285 -0.434844 0
        ...(points  coordinates) ...

        POLYGONS 109010 436040
        3 54060 54066 54200
        3 54206 54200 54066
        3 54204 54065 54200
        3 54060 54200 54065
        ...

        POINT_DATA 55181
        FIELD attributes 1
        p 1 55181 float
        -0.622929 -0.202063 -0.860382 ....
```

What I want to do is to visualize this file with python-vtk module, and output .png image. I can plot contour of this file in Paraview (see [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1eLr.png)) but when using python scripting the domain is white and no pressure distribution, which is weird (see [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIm6x.png)). I also attach my python code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import vtk
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
from vtk.util.numpy_support import vtk_to_numpy

# 0. set the vtk.file path
filePath = '.../p_zNormal.vtk'

# reader 
reader = vtk.vtkPolyDataReader()            # vtkDataSetReader()
reader.SetFileName(filePath)
reader.ReadAllScalarsOn()
reader.ReadAllVectorsOn()
reader.Update() 

vtkdata = reader.GetOutput()
scalar_range = vtkdata.GetScalarRange()     # (0.0, 1.0) ?

np_coordinates = vtk_to_numpy(vtkdata.GetPoints().GetData()) 

pointData = vtkdata.GetPointData()
fieldData_vtk_array = pointData.GetArray(0)    
fieldData_np_array = np.array(vtk_to_numpy(fieldData_vtk_array))

DataMin = np.min(fieldData_np_array)
DataMax = np.max(fieldData_np_array)

# look-up table
pColorTable = vtk.vtkLookupTable()
pColorTable.SetHueRange(0, 0.67)             # red -> blue
pColorTable.SetNumberOfTableValues(16)       # number of colors
pColorTable.SetTableRange(scalar_range)
pColorTable.SetValueRange(0.0, 1.0)
pColorTable.Build()

# mapper
mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
mapper.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())
mapper.SetScalarRange(DataMin,DataMax)
mapper.SetLookupTable(pColorTable)
mapper.ScalarVisibilityOn()
mapper.SetScalarModeToUsePointFieldData();
mapper.Update()

# actor
actor = vtk.vtkActor()
actor.SetMapper(mapper)

scalarBar = vtk.vtkScalarBarActor()
scalarBar.SetLookupTable(pColorTable)
scalarBar.SetTitle("p (Pa)")
scalarBar.SetNumberOfLabels(10)
#scalarBar.GetTitleTextProperty().SetColor(0, 0, 0);
#scalarBar.GetTitleTextProperty().SetFontFamilyToArial();
#scalarBar.GetTitleTextProperty().SetFontSize(20);
#scalarBar.GetLabelTextProperty().SetColor(0, 0, 0);
#scalarBar.SetLabelFormat("%5.3f");
#scalarBar.GetLabelTextProperty().SetFontFamilyToArial();
#scalarBar.GetLabelTextProperty().SetFontSize(20);
scalarBar.SetUnconstrainedFontSize(1)

# render 
ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
ren.AddActor(actor) 
ren.AddActor(scalarBar)               
ren.SetBackground(0.2, 0.3, 0.4)

# render window
renwin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renwin.AddRenderer(ren)             
renwin.SetWindowName("Test")
renwin.SetSize(800,600)
renwin.Render()

# interactor
iren = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
iren.SetRenderWindow(renwin)

iren.Initialize()
iren.Start()
```

It seems that I CANNOT upload the source file....
I would be very very appreciated if anyone could help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `reader.ReadAllFieldsOn()`.

Comment: Hi @mmusy, thanks for your suggestion! I have tried turn on all the settings of reader including ReadAllFields but it doesn't work... it seems that I don't specify the variable name for coloring. But I tried a few methods and failed.

Comment: Uhm maybe using GetFieldData() instead of GetPointData()?
Check out this: https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Cxx/PolyData/FieldData/